# Can't load google maps JavaScript file in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jquery, google-maps

I am building a SharePoint hosted app where I am retrieving the user's location in coordinates. I am trying to reverse geocode these coordinates using google maps api. But I can't load the google maps javascript file. I tried this:

$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false",successfunction);

The result was it calls "successfunction" but when I try to make geocoder object inside it like this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.geocoder();
```

It says "google is not defined". I searched on internet in most places it is suggested that the google maps js file is not actually loaded even though javascript calls the successfunction. So I tried this also:

$.getScript(
  "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=googleMapsLoaded");

But the function "googleMapsLoaded" is never called. I have also tried uploading the google maps js file to SharePoint style library and loading it from there but still is says "google is not defined"
I am out options now. If there is any better option to reverse geocode I am open for it so please suggest. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Save the script(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js) to your local and add it to scripts folder of your app solution in visual studio and load it in your default.aspx page.